# Eigenvalues of a matrix changed by a diagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-decomposition

Suppose we have a matrix $A=A^T$ with at least one eigenvalue repeated. Let's add a diagonal matrix $\text{diag}(c,2c,\dots, nc)$ to $A$, where $c \approx 0$. How do we know that the new symmetric matrix has no repeated eigenvalues?

Comment: What is the meaning of changing a matrix by a diagonal matrix?

Comment: Do you mean A+D, by changing the matrix?

Comment: Yes, $A+D$, edited.